# Retrieve specific data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database. This is the structure of my database

[image: database structure image]

I want to get the data of reference `XqU1a6jrvKSLf4ulhI3LkOhChE92` and child `ahmad` and display the `bikingTime` in the textView but I get `0`. I wrote this code in `MainActivity`

```
child mychild=new child();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    String name="ahmad";
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("XqU1a6jrvKSLf4ulhI3LkOhChE92").child(name);

    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            mychild = dataSnapshot.getValue(child.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    myRef.addValueEventListener(listener);
    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    test.setText(String.valueOf(mychild.getBikingTime()));
}
```

This is the `child` class:

```
public class child {
public int bikingTime=0;
public int noOfKicks=0;
public int noOfJumps=0;


public child() {
}

public child(int bikingTime, int noOfKicks, int noOfJumps) {
    this.bikingTime = bikingTime;
    this.noOfKicks = noOfKicks;
    this.noOfJumps = noOfJumps;
}

public int getBikingTime() {
    return bikingTime;
}

public void setBikingTime(int bikingTime) {
    this.bikingTime = bikingTime;
}

public int getNoOfKicks() {
    return noOfKicks;
}

public void setNoOfKicks(int noOfKicks) {
    this.noOfKicks = noOfKicks;
}

public int getNoOfJumps() {
    return noOfJumps;
}

public void setNoOfJumps(int noOfJumps) {
    this.noOfJumps = noOfJumps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these things add root node into query ..

```
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("child-activity-kit").child("XqU1a6jrvKSLf4ulhI3LkOhChE92").child(name);


  DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query=myRef.child("XqU1a6jrvKSLf4ulhI3LkOhChE92").child(name);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mychild = dataSnapshot.getValue(child.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: you give proper root node and child node key.

Comment: sorry,I did not understand

Comment: it means in firebase check root node name and child node name are given is same.

Comment: remove root node and try it.

Comment: put debugger and check it going into onDatachange method or not.

Comment: put debugger and check it going into onDatachange method or not

Comment: if dataSnapshot is not null then it give value,

Comment: I put debugger. and yes data is read from the firebase but it is not saved in the fields of "mychild".

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as follow. It should work.

```
child mychild=new child();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

        FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        String name="ahmad";
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("XqU1a6jrvKSLf4ulhI3LkOhChE92").child(name);

        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mychild = dataSnapshot.getValue(child.class);
                test.setText(String.valueOf(mychild.getBikingTime()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        myRef.addValueEventListener(listener);


    }
```

Comment: it reads the data from firebase but it does not save it in fields of object "child". once we go out of onDataChange function all variables are back to zero

Comment: can you help on how to save the data

Comment: Hey buddy, sorry for late response as i didn't get notified about your comments. As you are using Firebase Realtime Database, to learn about saving data to database, you can read the official documentations from Firebase website https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write. If you get stuck, post a new question and people will help you. I am experienced with Firebase Realtime database, so you can post a link to your question as a comment here to notify me. I will help you out if i know the answer. I am still learning though.

Comment: By the way, if my answer above is correct or helpful to you, please mark it as Answer or vote up so i can gain more reputation. Thank you